# Redirect to tab on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a link on the tab of the visualforce(there are two tabs on my visualforce page).On click of link it redirects to another visualforce page where user  updates information and on save it redirects back to the visualforce page but not on tab of the visualforce page from where it is clicked on.Below is the save method where it redirects to visualforce page but not to tab on visualforce page.

```
public PageReference Save(){
update oh;
PageReference oPage = new PageReference ('/apex/HistoryPage?Id=' + oh.Account__c); 
oPage.setRedirect(true);
return oPage   
}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is "When loading a VF page with tabs, can we choose which tab is initially selected?", the answer is "yes".

In the `apex:tabPanel` you can use the `selectedTab` attribute to set which tab is selected when the page loads.

> `selectedTab`:  **Object**
>
> The name of the default selected tab when the page
>   loads. This value must match the name attribute on a child tab
>   component. If the value attribute is defined, the selectedTab
>   attribute is ignored."

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm

To get this working, try adding a URL parameter and make sure to get it in your VF Pages constructor.

*Example:*

In your save() method that outputs the redirect

```
public PageReference Save(){
    update oh;
    string selectedTab='';
    // determine which tab to be selected when you load the next page
    PageReference oPage = new PageReference ('/apex/HistoryPage?Id=' + oh.Account__c+'selectedTab='+selectedTab); 
    oPage.setRedirect(true);
    return oPage; 
}
```

Then in `HistoryPage`'s controller:

```
public class HistoryPageController{
    private final id accountId;
    public string selectedTab {get;set;}

    public static set<string> tabNameList=new set<string>{
        'Account','Contacts','Cases'
    };
    public static string defaultTabName='Account';

    public HistoryPageController(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        this.accountId=con.getId();

        // set selectedTab, if blank or not in tabNameList, set to default tab
        this.selectedTab=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedTab');

        if(string.isBlank(selectedTab) || !HistoryPageController.tabNameList.contains(selectedTab))
            selectedTab=HistoryPageController.defaultTabName;

        // everything else . . .

    }//END init(ApexPages.StandardController con)
}//END HistoryPageController
```

Comment: I don't want the tab as default selectedTab.Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: did you read the entry in the link?

Comment: check out my update.  does that address what you are looking for?  could you please explain what you are looking for if this doesn't suffice?